# Java ClassCastException on Data Member

Tags: java

I have the following: class BaseModel contains BaseForm:

```
public class BaseModel {
    BaseForm form;

    public BaseForm getForm() { return form; }
    public void setForm(BaseForm form) { this.form = form; }
}
```

Class MyModel extends BaseModel; class MyForm extends BaseForm. In other words, there is parallel inheritance,

> MyModel -> BaseModel
>
> MyForm -> BaseForm

```
public class MyModel extends BaseModel { 
    // ... 'form' (inner data member) is set to MyForm which extends BaseForm
}
```

The following gives me a ClassCaseException. I need to receive the specific Form contained in this specific model:

```
MyForm myForm = (MyForm)specificModel.getForm();
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: BaseForm cannot be cast to MyForm

I understand that I can't cast to a specific class, but what should I do?

Comment: You could try using interfaces instead of your class hierarchy.

Comment: You can absolutely cast to a specific class,  what you're getting is a runtime exception because what you put in there wasn't actually an instance of MyForm. The problem is not in the code you're shown but wherever you call setForm with something other than an instance of MyForm.

Answer (score 2):

If the object you set to the member `form` in `MyModel` is actually a `MyForm` (not a `BaseForm`), then the exception won't be thrown. Please see below for example (I have tested the code):

```
public class MyModel extends BaseModel { 

    // ... 'form' (inner data member) is set to MyForm which extends BaseForm
    MyModel(MyForm mf) {
        this.form = mf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyForm mf = new MyForm();
        MyModel specificModel = new MyModel(mf);
        MyForm myForm = (MyForm) specificModel.getForm();  // No exception now
    }
}

public class BaseModel {
    BaseForm form;

    public BaseForm getForm() { return form; }
    public void setForm(BaseForm form) { this.form = form; }
}

public class MyForm extends BaseForm {
}

public class BaseForm {
}
```